# Calculation on multiple columns and aggregate values by multiple factors level

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Price=seq(1, 1.5, 0.1),
                 Sales=seq(6, 1, -1),
                 Quality=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
                 Brand=c('F','P','P','P','F','F'))
```

Sometimes I need to do some complicated calculation on multiple columns and aggregate values by multiple factors level. For a simplified example, if I want to get `Revenue (= Price * Sales)` distribution within each `Quality` and split by `Brand`, I would do

```
df$Revenue <- df$Price*df$Sales

RevSumByQ <- aggregate(Revenue~Quality, data=df, sum)
colnames(RevSumByQ)[2] <- "RevSumByQ"
df <- merge(df, RevSumByQ)

RevSumWithinQByB <- aggregate(RevSumByQ~Brand, data=df, sum)
colnames(RevSumWithinQByB)[2] <- "RevSumWithinQByB"
df <- merge(df, RevSumWithinQByB)

df$RevDistWithinQByB = df$RevSumByQ/df$RevSumWithinQByB
df

  Brand Quality Price Sales Revenue RevSumByQ RevSumWithinQByB RevDistWithinQByB
1     F       A   1.0     6     6.0      16.3             32.7         0.4984709
2     F       B   1.4     2     2.8       8.2             32.7         0.2507645
3     F       B   1.5     1     1.5       8.2             32.7         0.2507645
4     P       A   1.1     5     5.5      16.3             40.8         0.3995098
5     P       A   1.2     4     4.8      16.3             40.8         0.3995098
6     P       B   1.3     3     3.9       8.2             40.8         0.2009804
```

If show in a plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Brand, y=RevDistWithinQByB, fill=Quality)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

There should be better way to draw this plot but my main interest here is to get the data frame with less intermediate results(`Revenue, RevSumByQ, RevSumWithinQByB`). I can see a structure in my approach so I wonder if there're more elegant solutions or there're already some functions that facilitate this kind of task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `dplyr`

```
res <- df %>%
         group_by(Quality) %>% 
         mutate(Revenue= Price*Sales,RevSumByQ=sum(Revenue)) %>% 
         group_by(Brand) %>% 
         mutate(RevSumWithinQByB= sum(RevSumByQ),
             RevDistWithinQByB= RevSumByQ/RevSumWithinQByB )
```

Comment: You could simplify your first mutate to: `mutate(RevSumByQ=sum(Price*Sales)) %>% ` since Revenue is not needed afterwards

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Yes, I did thought about that,  but then was thinking may be the OP needed that column for something ...:-)

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
##
df[,Revenue:=Price*Sales][
  ,RevSumByQ:=sum(Revenue),
  by=Quality][
    ,RevSumWithinQByB:=sum(RevSumByQ),
    by=Brand][
      ,RevDistWithinQByB:=RevSumByQ/RevSumWithinQByB]
```

And although I typically don't do this myself, you can call your `ggplot` code from inside of the same object:

```
df[,Revenue:=Price*Sales][
  ,RevSumByQ:=sum(Revenue),
  by=Quality][
    ,RevSumWithinQByB:=sum(RevSumByQ),
    by=Brand][
      ,RevDistWithinQByB:=RevSumByQ/RevSumWithinQByB][
        ,{print(ggplot(
            data=.SD,
            aes(x=Brand,
                y=RevDistWithinQByB,
                fill=Quality))+
            geom_bar(stat="identity"))}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically (as stated by @arun) you don't need merges here, and you can do everything using `ave` from base R. It also seems like it is going to be hard to skip the first two aggregation steps. Though you can skip last calculation and put it directly into `ggplot`. Something like:

```
df$Revenue <- df$Price*df$Sales
df$RevSumByQ <- with(df, ave(Revenue, Quality, FUN = sum))
df$RevSumWithinQByB <- with(df, ave(RevSumByQ, Brand, FUN = sum))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = Brand, y = RevSumByQ/RevSumWithinQByB, fill = Quality)) +
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]